# How to guess the type and encoding of a file given it's name in Go?

Tags: go

I'm looking for a quick way to guess the mime type and encoding of a file in Go, given it's name. In Python, you can do something as simple as:

```
import mimetypes
type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(file_name)
```

Does go have something similar? I see the mimetypes package, but I don't think it is capable of deriving the encoding from a file name.

Comment: Is the problem that you want to guess the type via file magic rather than the extension (which, in Python, requires a third-party library, not `mimetypes`), or that you don't know whether a function named [`TypeByExtension`](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/#TypeByExtension) can guess the type by the file extension the way Python's `mimetypes.guess_type` can?

Answer (score 3):

Use [mime.TypeByExtension](https://godoc.org/mime#TypeByExtension) to get the mime type given a file extension:

```
fmt.Println(mime.TypeByExtension(".jpg"))  // prints image/jpeg
```

If starting with a full file name, use [filepath.Ext](https://godoc.org/path/filepath#Ext) to get the extension and pass that extension  to the function above:

```
fmt.Println(mime.TypeByExtension(filepath.Ext("blah.gif")))  // prints image/gif
```